# How to get Stats of a Zookeeper node using Curator framework

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am using curator framework in java to interact with ZNodes.
How do we get node stats like last_modified time and creation time etc. I could do same in python using kazoo framework.

```
from kazoo.client import KazooClient

zk_client = KazooClient(hosts='127.0.0.1:2181')
zk_client.start()
data, stat = zk_client.get("/my/favorite")
```

Ref. Link: [kazoo](https://kazoo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html)

I tried searching similar support via curator and couldn't get result. Kindly help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curator (note I'm the main author of Curator) wraps the standard ZooKeeper Java API so all the same methods are there. So, to get the Stat object:

```
CuratorFramework client = ....
Stat stat = client.checkExists().forPath(path);
```

Comment: Thanks Randgalt. That was helpful for me.